# Add Regional Language in Google Assistant?

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

Can one add regional language oneself to Google Assistant? Is there any library, tool, etc. available to incorporate support for regional languages, not supported by Google?

Answer (score 1):

No, the language models are not user updateable.

Comment: Thanks.  So can you suggest any other way or tool to add unsupported languages.

Comment: Lobby Google to support it